# LVM2: Where is the volume backup file documented?

Tags: backup, documentation, lvm2

I need to know the units of the various numbers present in the LVM `.../backup/vg_XXXX` file - the one that contains the detailed lvm structure for a disk.

Where can I find documentation (info, man page, online link) on the contents of this file? I'm using Fedora 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of LVM version 2.02.86(2) (2011-07-08), the only documentation of this file is in the file itself -- which is very minimal.

Hopefully, LVM folks are reading this and will choose to document this file better in future.